# Asp.net Mvc Setting an attribute of any model which contains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have is_valid attribute in almost all of my model. I want to update is_valid attribute of any objects which contains this attribute ?

How can i do this ? Should i learn repository pattern ?

One of my model as seen as below :

```
public class HrFileType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dosya Tipinin Adı")]
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "İkaz Periyodu(Gün)")]        
    public Int64? NotificationPeriod { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Açıklama")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public bool is_valid { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HrMapPersonFile> HrMapPersonFile { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most straight forward approach:

```
public class BaseModel 
{
    public bool is_valid { get; set; }
}

public class HrFileType : BaseModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dosya Tipinin Adı")]
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "İkaz Periyodu(Gün)")]        
    public Int64? NotificationPeriod { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Açıklama")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HrMapPersonFile> HrMapPersonFile { get; set; }

}
```

And your Update method can be:

```
void markValid(BaseModel model)
{
    model.is_valid = true;
}
```

**Update:**

For your File Upload case:
Create another Base Class:

```
public class FileUploadBaseModel : BaseModel
{
    //properties you need for file upload
}
```

And in your model that need fileupload:

```
public class SomeModelName: FileUploadBaseModel 
{
    //properties specific for this model
}
```

Comment: So if i want get the "created user" or "modified user" attributes for all models, i can add to the model. This is awesome :) I could not think. But what can i do if i want to implement this approach to the file upload ? Do you have an idea for me ?

Comment: @modulerica are you going to have file upload on each of your model, or only a small set of them?

Comment: I will have file upload in my 10 model.